# A more effective way to structure database for pivots

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

To describe the question as good as possible, I'll detail the actual scenario:
The site will allow users to add IP's for monitoring them against RBL's. In doing so, I've been pondering different approaches to structuring the database in a manner that is as optimal as possible in terms of efficiency for large IP blocks, whilst still being workable.

The project is built on Laravel, and I've set up a database structure containing:

> *table_a*
>
> Contains information about the IP we monitor.
>
> - id (auto inc, primary)
> - name (varchar, 128) **Friendly name for the monitor**
> - ip (varchar, 16) **The IP to monitor**
> - email (varchar, 128) **An e-mail for notifications**
> - notifications (tinyint, 1) **A toggle for notifications**
> - timestamps

-

> *table_b*
>
> Contains information about the RBL's we monitor against.
>
> - id (auto inc, primary)
> - url (varchar, 255) **The URL for the monitor**
> - active (tinyint, 1) **Toggle for whether we actively check toward it or not**

-

> table_a_b
>
> A pivot table to maintain the status of each RBL in.
>
> - table_a_id (int, 10) **Foreign key to id on table_a**
> - table_b_id (int, 10) **Foreign key to id on table_b**
> - listed (tinyint, 1) **Whether or not the IP is listed on this RBL**
> - notified (tinyint, 1) **Whether or not we've already notified the user**

**So the way it currently works** is that when adding an IP, it adds the IP into table_a, as well as `(number of rows in table_b * number of IP's)` into the pivot table. Whilst adding it doesn't take that long - the issue I see is that adding a /24 of IP's (256 IP's) tracked against (currently) 87 RBL's creates a grand total of *22,272 records*. That's for a /24. A /22 (1024 IP's) would be 89,088 records. That's a pretty large amount for a single user, and I can see how that'd quickly destroy database performance.

The alternative I've thought of is to keep a column named `listed_on` on `table_a` which is a list of any RBL they are listed in. The row would contain something along the line of `55|32|11` - which would be simple enough to parse in PHP. Still, with a large number of users, I can see that hitting PHP performance instead with a large amount of string handling.

Am I missing an obvious solution here, or are these two ones (perhaps especially the latter) the best bet?

Cheers!

Comment: @philipxy Because it **is** a pivot table? It's the table managing the relation between an RBL, and IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward relational design (instead of `table_a_b(ip, rbl, ...)`) is tables `listed(ip, rbl)` "ip IP is listed on rbl RBL" and `notified(ip, rbl)` "user has been notifed that ip IP is listed on rbl RBL". Relational tables are intended to hold the rows that make a true *proposition* (statement) from some table-specific *predicate* (sentence template parameterized by columns). Tables that should contain a row for every possible value for a column or columns are rare.

Whether instead a design should be used that combines these tables depends on your predicates and the constraints that follow from applying them to all the situations that can arise. Eg if notifications only ever happen to listed IP-RBL pairs then maybe best is `ip_rbl(ip, rbl, notified)` "ip IP is in rbl RBL and NOTIFIED is whether user has been notified". (Here the tradeoff is more smaller tables & more joins vs fewer larger tables & more searching.)

PS Pivot tables are not generally best for manipulating & querying data compared to the unpivoted data. They can be appropriate for formatting final output to humans or for moving between data and metadata. See [this news post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.databases.theory/Hjj_lxB8pXE/xAEtfKX8EKcJ). (I saw your pivot table as unpivoted since the boolean column names aren't data values even though it is a table that is total on IP-RBL.)

Comment: That's so simple that I'm furious I didn't think of it myself. Splitting it up to have a separate pivot where I only attach **listed** IP's is of course a great approach, and minimizes the amount of rows. Well done sir, you have my sincere appreciation for being the logical one out of the two of us!

Comment: It seems your posing this question showed biases in point of view in both of us--you for pivot tables in seeing only the pivoted design, me for unpivoted tables in not seeing table as pivoted but only unpivoted.